# Bulgarian dataset for sentiment analysis or comment helpfulness

Tags: data-request, products, sentiment-analysis

My team is researching solutions about sentiment analysis or comment(preferably product review) helpfulness in Bulgarian. Anybody know a good source for those? The comment health one is a long shot for sure, but at least somebody should know a sentiment labeled dataset. Any other suggestions would also be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

### [Dataset for "Customer Feedback-Text Analysis for Online Stores Reviews in Bulgarian"](https://dataverse.harvard.edu/dataset.xhtml?persistentId=doi:10.7910/DVN/TXIK9P)

The dataset Customer_feedback_bg consists of customer reviews for online stores in Bulgarian. The data are retrieved from otzivi.bg and pazaruvaj.com, and represent user reviews in Bulgarian language about 87 online stores. 906 customer reviews were collected in free text and manually associated with the following categories: compliments, complaints, mixed, suggestions.
Наборът от данни Customer_feedback_bg се състои от потребителски отзиви за онлайн магазини на български език. Данните са получени от otzivi.bg и pazaruvaj.com и представляват потребителски отзиви на български език за 87 онлайн магазина. Събрани са 906 потребителски отзива в свободен текст, които са ръчно асоциирани със следните категории: похвали, оплаквания, смесени, препоръки.